# CRSM return CME Error code 23 when access EFkc

Tags: android, gsm, at-command, modem

This is my first on stack overflow so please forgive me if missed something.
We are trying to extract the Kc number from SIM card using android A72 as a USB modem, Minicom on ubuntu 20, and charger cable to connect them.

On the phone USB debug is enable + 3gpp AT commands from developer option , so once I connect the phone with the laptop ttyACM0 shows up and Minicom runs without any problems

We could run testing commands like `AT`, `AT+COPS?`, and `AT+CRSM=176,28424,0,0,33` we got the results without any errors

then we tried to access the EFkc to extract the data

1- we tried the file id based on SIM structure - EFkc = 6F20 (decimal 28448)
`AT+CRSM=176,28448,0,0,9 +CRSM: 106,130,""`
which is after searching **File not found**

2- we tried the file id based on SIM structure - EFkcGPRS = 6F52 (decimal 28498)
`AT+CRSM=176,28498,0,0,9 +CRSM: 106,130,""`

3- we tried the id's of USIM structure for the same two EFs - EFkc= 4F20 (decimal 20256) & EFkcGPRS =  4F52 (decimal 20306)

`AT+CRSM=176,20306,0,0,9 +CME ERROR: memory failure`

`AT+CRSM=176,20256,0,0,9 +CME ERROR: memory failure`

we were relying on this file as a reference for the [file's structure](https://dione.lib.unipi.gr/xmlui/bitstream/handle/unipi/8284/Andi_Anastasis.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y)
well, we got accessed to multiple values except for the once inside the GSM-ACCESS which will return the memory failure

what would the reason for the memory failure ? how could it be fixed ?

- Note: CSIM is not supported